# scheduling a task at the beginning of the animation frame using requestAnimationFrame

Tags: javascript, performance, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, requestanimationframe

I am using `requestAnimationFrame` to schedule dom manipulations. Why is the task getting executed almost at the end of each frame?

[image: Timeline overview]

Often the tasks are a bit lengthy and overlaps with the next frame. Is there a way to make sure the task is scheduled to start at the beginning of the animation frame?

Here is the full code — https://jsbin.com/guzoholosa/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Apparently, the vertical line shows when a frame was *painted*. If you zoom-in you'll see `Frame start` micro-block right at the beginning of a code block: https://puu.sh/rfpBL/20d82f6be7.png It was painted early because there was nothing else scheduled that could change the frame.

Comment: I couldn't find `Frame start` micro block anywhere in the timeline.